# move_base robot movement wrong direction

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo @All,

I am using a custom robot. I want to use move_base, either with defining a goal by clicking in the map, ob by using a move_base_square.py script. In rviz I see the thin blue line, as the computed path, but the robot is moving in an other direction, with short flashing red line in different directions. When using
a nave-Square script or using the arbotixGUI the robot ist moving correct.
A screenshot of rviz you can find here: [www.kunst-raum.de/files/screenshot.png](http://www.kunst-raum.de/files/screenshot.png) Because I am very new to ROS I actually have no idea where to look to solve this problem.

I hope that somebody here may help me in this point.

Thanks a lot

Michael, Berlin, Germany

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62051/move_base--robot-movement-wrong-direction/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Michael,

How many and what is the relationship of the coordinate frames are you using? Try adding a 'TF' tree to the view in RVIZ, and see if they are displaying as expected.

You can also look at section 2 here and see if that helps:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide

Cheers,
Gavin

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-05-06**:
Hi Gavin, in the TF-Tree I see /base_link, /map, /odom all with transform ok. Changing fixed_frame in Global from map to something else didnt change the reaction. The real robot is moving forward for about one second then moves backward since it leaves the map. At this point I use no laser

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-05-06**:
Can you view the output to the motor (rostopic echo /cmd_vel) and see if it's giving you a positive x command?

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-05-06**:
Hi Gavin, first of all I would like to thank you for your friendly answers. I updated my question to respond to your question. Today I will try to rewrite our basecontroller_node, to see if something will change. btw. Nice Hackerspace you have.